# How to override Drupal behaviors?

Tags: 8, javascript

I want to override the drupal core behavior `Drupal.behaviors.filePreviewLinks` which is located at `core\modules\file\file.js` from my custom module

I tried placing the following code in js file of my custom module

```
Drupal.behaviors.filePreviewLinks = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
        console.log($(context).find('div.js-form-managed-file .file a'));
        //some custom code
    },
    detach: function (context, settings){
       //some custom code
    }
};
```

But it is not working. What I need to do? How to override Drupal core behavior in custom module?

**EDIT**

Let me explain my actual question. I am loading a form in page that is created using ECK entity type module. One of a field in form has 'file' as field type. So once I upload a file, it is showing filename with link in a table(I hope it is default drupal feature). I want to remove the file link and show only file name.

Comment: Not enough info here. Are you attaching this file to the page?

Comment: `delete Drupal.behaviors.filePreviewLinks.attach; Drupal.behaviors.filePreviewLinks.detach;` in your own library loaded afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do something similar in the [Node Revision Delete](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_revision_delete) module to override the drupal.content_types library doing this:

In the *.libraries.yml file define your library:

```
content_types:
  version: 1.0.0
  js:
    js/content_types.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/drupal
    - core/drupal.form
```

Attack your library where you need it:

```
  // Element to track the content type.
  $form['workflow']['section']['node_revision_delete_track'] = [
    '#type' => 'checkbox',
    '#title' => t('Limit the amount of revisions for this content type'),
    '#default_value' => $track,
    '#attached' => [
      'library' => [
        'node_revision_delete/content_types',
        'node_revision_delete/admin_settings',
      ],
    ],
  ];
```

And remove the core library:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_library_info_alter().
 */
function node_revision_delete_library_info_alter(&$libraries, $extension) {
    unset($libraries['drupal.content_types']);
}
```

Comment: This helps to override entire library file. It is working fine and I up-voted for this. Thanks. But, is it possible to override only particular behavior instead of entire library?

Comment: @siddiq I don't know (is the first time that I see a problem like this), but you can duplicate the file and rewrite the function that you need to change.

Answer (score 5):

### Use [`libraries-override`](https://www.drupal.org/i/2216195#override-extend) in your theme's info.yml file

**Step 1: Find the library name in core that the JS or CSS file to override belongs to.**

For example, it is clear that `core\modules\file\file.js`  belongs to the `file` module. Review at `core/modules/file/file.libraries.yml` to find the library name .  In the yaml file, the library name is the top-level item in the yaml structure where `file.js` is defined.  In this case `drupal.file`.

```yaml
#core/modules/file/file.libraries.yml
drupal.file:
  version: VERSION
  js:
    file.js: {}  #### Drupal 8+ defines the js/css to override in libraries.yml
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/jquery.once
    - core/drupal
    - core/drupalSettings
```

**Step 2: Find the fully-qualified library name.**

The fully-qualified library name is generally prefixed by the module name, in the format `<modulename>/<libraryname>`. However, some core system libraries don't follow this format, so if unsure of the fully qualified library name, search for instances of the `<libraryname>` in the core codebase, which may turn up a string with the fully-qualified library name like `drupal/<libraryname>`.

In this case the fully qualified name is `file/drupal.file`.

**Step 3: Override the file in your theme**

In your custom theme's info.yml file add the following lines:

```yaml
libraries-override:
  file/drupal.file:
    js:
      file.js: js/file.js
```

If you want to override a core or contrib CSS file, the syntax is similar:

```yaml
libraries-override:
  filter/caption:
    css:
      theme: # <-- this line must match the definition in libraries.yml
        css/filter.caption.css: css/components/captions.css
#        ^                       ^
#        |                       |
#      File path as defined     File path relative to your
#      in *.libraries.yml       theme's folder.
```

**Step 4: Copy the file into your theme, and modify it to your needs**

For the 2 examples given above, you'd place the files.js inside a folder `js` in your theme, and you'd rename filter.caption.css to captions.css and place it inside the `css/components` folder of your theme.

**Step 5: Clear caches and reload the page.**

Use your Web browser's resource inspector to verify the path to the overridden file is coming from your theme folder.

Answer (score 4):

Since Drupal behaviors are really just javascript objects, all you need to do is to ensure that the behavior you're overwriting is loaded before your replacement. So:

**my_module.libraries.yml**

```
some_new_lib:
  js:
    my-js-file.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - libary_with/behavior_you_want_to_override
    - core/jquery   # anything else you need
```

**my-js.file**

```
(function ($) {

  Drupal.behaviors.nameOfBehaviorYouWantToOverride = {
    // Your little dash of magic
  }

})(jQuery);
```